# Unable to validate html due to missing quotation for = string

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

I am getting this error `"Error: = in an unquoted attribute value. Probable causes: Attributes running together or a URL query string in an unquoted attribute value."` when i try to validate my document.

This is my code:

```
print("<a href=" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '?id=' . $student->hentId() . ">" . $student->hentNavn() . "</a><br/>\n");
```

The HTML output looks like this:

```
<a href=/StudentDatabase/StudentRegister.php?id=1>Petter Andersen</a><br/>
```

How can I properly add quotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add quotes by escaping them with \

do you want the id=1 to be in the url? My guess it that is the attribute it thinks is missing quotes

```
print("<a href=\" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '?id=' . $student->hentId() . \">" . $student->hentNavn() . "</a><br/>\n");
```

Comment: Yes that's right, but wouldn't that be '?id=' and isn't that quoted correctly?

Comment: I had to update a couple times but I think the id=1 is but the actual full url does not show quotes so change href=\" and \">"

Comment: Hmm I tried but now $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] doesn't work and $student->hentId() wants a semicolon between hentId and ()

Comment: It seems the underlying issue might lie in the $_SERVER["php_SELF"] part

Comment: print("<a href=\"" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?id=" . $student->hentId() . "\">" . $student->hentNavn() . "</a><br/>\n"); work?

Comment: It now says that the first tag in "PHP_SELF" is not closed and the </a> does not match another tag

Comment: Disregard previous comment!! it worked! :-D Thank you

Comment: put this in the top of the page 

$nice_url = urlencode(. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '?id=' . $student->hentId() .);
then:
echo "<a href=\"$nice_url\">" . $student->hentNavn() . "</a><br/>\n";

Comment: Could be required sanitize the link, the web-site can end affected by an XSS vulnerability similar to this http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Answer (score 1):

Is not safe use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` directly in links. Depending on your code, the web-site could be vulnerable to XSS and unwanted JavaScript could end injected just visiting `page/url/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('xss')%3C
/script%3E%3Cfoo%22`. The same for `student id` or `student name`, if this records are not sanitized the `html` could end broken or be vulnerable to XSS.

Is recommended use functions `rawurlencode`, `urlencode`, `htmlspecialchars` to sanitize the link generated.

```
<?php
$url = rawurlencode($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?id=" . urlencode($student->hentId());
?>

<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?>">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($student->hentNavn()); ?>
</a>
```